# How to add css for ion-menu in ionic 4 as there is no app.css is available?

Tags: angular7, ionic4, ion-menu

I want to design the ion-menu and implement css in the menu but where we will write the css i am not getting as there is no app.css is available.
I want to add the categories and inside that i want to add sub categories but from the web service. How to do this please help me.

I have tried but i am able to show the menu options static not dynamic which i will get from the api.
Please guide me what to do.

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu contentId="content" side="start">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <div *ngFor="let p of pages">
        <ion-menu-toggle *ngIf="p.url">
          <ion-item [routerLink]="p.url" routerDirection="root" routerLinkActive="active">
            <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>
              {{p.title}}
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-item button *ngIf="p.children?.length > 0" (click)="p.open = !p.open" [class.parent-active]="p.open"
          style="font-weight: 500;" detail="false">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="arrow-forward" *ngIf="!p.open"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="arrow-down" *ngIf="p.open"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-list *ngIf="p.open">
          <ion-menu-toggle>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let sub of p.children" class="sub-item" style="padding-left: 20px;
                  font-size: small;" [routerLink]="sub.url" routerDirection="root" routerLinkActive="active"
              style="--ion-text-color: var(--ion-color-primary);">
              <ion-icon [name]="sub.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{ sub.title }}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet [swipeGesture]="false" id="content" main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

I want the dynamic data to display in the side menu and design the side menu.

app.component.ts

```
pages = [
    {
      title: 'Main',
      url: '/home',
      icon: 'home'
    },
    {
      title: 'Categories',
      children: [
        {
          title: 'categories',
          url: '/categories',
          icon: 'arrow-dropright'
        },
        {
          title: 'wishlist',
          url: '/wishlist',
          icon: 'arrow-dropright'
        }, {
          title: 'Your Orders',
          url: '/your-orders',
          icon: 'arrow-dropright'
        }, {
          title: 'My Profile',
          url: '/profile',
          icon: 'play'
        }
      ]
    }, {
      title: 'Offers',
      children: [
        {
          title: 'categories',
          url: '/categories',
          icon: 'play'
        },
        {
          title: 'wishlist',
          url: '/wishlist',
          icon: 'play'
        },
      ]
    }, {
      title: 'LogOut',
      url: '/user-login',
      icon: 'log-out'
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **style** below **ion-content**

for example this will make your ion-menu background black.Like that do for other elements inside your menu

```
<style>
   ion-content{
    background:black;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add app.componet.scss in src directory. And you have to add styleUrls to Component decorator like below:

`@Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})`